# unable to pass read input to cat path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

New to bash here. I am trying to pass a read input to a filepath for a `cat` command.

```
read -p "enter folder" folderid
read -p "enter port (optional)if not required press 0:" port
if [$folderid -ne 0 && $port -ne 0];then
  new_interface=$(cat /var/abc/def/xyz_$fileid/randomfile)
  echo "$new_interface"
fi
```

Sample input for folderid: 134567

I get an error stating:

```
-bash: [134567: command not found
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong, tried different things nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell's tokenizer is white-space sensitive. Words are split at white-space and special characters such as `;`, `&`, `&&` and others. Use

```
if [ $folderid -ne 0 -a $port -ne 0 ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after the `[`, and the complete error free script should be

```
read -p "enter folder" folderid
read -p "enter port (optional)if not required press 0:" port

if [ "$folderid" -ne 0 ] && [ "$port" -ne 0 ]; then
    new_interface="$(</var/abc/def/xyz_$fileid/randomfile)"
    echo "$new_interface"
fi
```

If `folderid` is expected to be a string use

```
if [ ! -z "$folderid" ] && [ "$port" -ne "0" ];then
```

Also, remove the useless-use-of-cat in

```
new_interface=$(cat /var/abc/def/xyz_$fileid/randomfile)
```

to just

```
new_interface="$(</var/abc/def/xyz_$fileid/randomfile)"
```

Comment: thanks! but the error changed now:

Comment: -bash: [: missing `]'

Comment: @user3055304: Refer my update which solve your problem.